# Syntax error displaying javascript from mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have saved the JavaScript in a MySQL Database with phpMyAdmin. When I display it on the front end from the database using php it is showing as string, not as JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript code in the database:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://i0.poll.fm/survey.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
   <noscript><a href="http://rohan44.polldaddy.com/s/test">Take Our Survey!</a></noscript>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     polldaddy.add( {
       type: 'button',
       title: 'Take Our Survey!',
       style: 'inline',
       text_color: '000000',
       domain: 'rohan44.polldaddy.com/s/',
       id: 'A8D2AA9FAF96DA61'
     } );
   </script>
```

Here's the PHP page:

```
  <?php $xy=mysql_query("select * from survey where id=1");
   $row=mysql_fetch_row($xy);
   echo '<div id="survey">'.$row[1].'</div>'; ?>
```

How can this work as JavaScript?

Comment: I don't even know where to start ...

Comment: @rdlowrey: with a stiff drink

Comment: In the front end it is reading string not the javascript tag.

Comment: Do you want it to display just the javascript code?  Or actually insert the script into your page?

Comment: can you please clarify what "it is reading string" means?

Comment: mean it is showing the <script> tag in the front end

Comment: Your html is probably being escaped/htmlencoded before being saved to the database. What do you see on phpMyAdmin? I'm guessing something like `&lt;script (...)`.

Comment: yes. it is escaped /htmlencoded.

Comment: So just `echo '<div id="survey">'. html_entity_decode($row[1]).'</div>';`. Or just don't encode before saving to the database. Actually, I don't understand *why* you are saving this kind of content on a database...

Comment: Saving this sort of content to a database is a pretty bad idea. Not escaping it is probably a worse idea. If this is a script you want to run on the page, simply include it from another file: the database is overkill and asking for all sorts of hackery.

Answer (score 0):

First try commenting your echo line in the PHP and put this in its place:

```
var_dump($row);
```

This will let you see all the data in $row. I suspect that your script data is not in $row[1] but maybe in $row[2]. By using var_dump, you will see everything that is in $row and where it is.

If, after checking $row with var_dump, you don't see your data in there anywhere, you then need to make sure your query is correct. Run the query yourself and see what results you get. If you see the correct results when you run the query, make sure that the database is selected in the script. You may have to do something like

```
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
```

First before your query will work.

Comment: It's probably in row[0], but regardless he's piping javascript from a database into a php response? He should probably just include it from a file. Why use a database for that?